# How to pass data through Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is the piece of my dropdown list:

```
<li><label>City:</label>
    <select id="car" id="city">
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

**Ajax code:**

```
$("#SaveChanges").click(function () {
    var data = {
        email: $('#email').val(),
        firstname:   $('#firstname').val(),
        lastname:   $('#lastname').val(),
        city:   $('#city option:selected').text()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax/saveChanges');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I want to send all the data to ajax function. I am getting all the details there except city.

Comment: Your `<select>` has two id attribute `id="car" id="city"` remove the first one.

Comment: Why are you using async: false btw? You do know that doint that will hang the whole page until the server sends a response, don't you?

Comment: Also, from a readability point of view, I would really start employing some [proper indentation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) when writing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
$( "#city" ).val();
```

Your select have to look like this:

```
<li><label>City:</label>
    <select id="city">
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the val() function for the select:

```
$('#city').val()
```

That will give you the value.

Note that the value is not the same as the display text, in that case you'll want to use the text() function.